# Uninstall Mozart

Tags: ubuntu, oz, mozart

I installed the Mozart programming system to my Ubuntu 16.04 machine via apt-get.

I attempted to reinstall Mozart by issuing a `sudo apt-get remove mozart` command at the terminal, but accidently left `ozc` and other dependencies in place. Upon attempting to reinstall the system, I was notified of the following error: "... Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Is there an simple way to remove the original contents packaged together with `mozart`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `sudo apt purge mozart` instead.

If the `... Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` error persists, then try executing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` to solve it.